# Getting Computer System Information using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to build a python script that will grab certain information about a system running mostly Windows or Linux. Here is what I got so far.

```
import socket
import os 
import sys
import platform
import psutil
import uuid

print  "Name: " +socket.gethostname() 
print "FQDN: " +socket.getfqdn()
print "System Platform: "+sys.platform
print "Machine: " +platform.machine()
print "Node " +platform.node()
print "Platform: "+platform.platform()
print "Pocessor: " +platform.processor()
print "System OS: "+platform.system()
print "Release: " +platform.release()
print "Version: " +platform.version()
print "Number of CPUs: " +str(psutil.cpu_count()) 
print "Number of Physical CPUs: " +str(psutil.cpu_count(logical=False))
#Need  Model of Computer i.e.  HP Compaq 8100 Elite SFF, HP X600 workstation
#need Ram
#need Disk space
#Need Manufacturer i.e. HP, Dell, Lenova
```

I am not sure how to get the Model Number of the System, and the Manufacturer both in Linux and Windows.  I think I am able to get the RAM and Disk Space using psutil.

Comment: Hmm, could you also run say a shell command and get info from like df and whatnot?

Comment: I could use shell to do this but wondering if it was possible to do this in python.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an [article](http://amitsaha.github.io/site/notes/articles/python_linux/article.html) sometime back which you may find useful. However, it is written exclusively for Linux and besides using some standard library modules, it directly reads data from the files in `/proc` and uses the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to execute Linux commands in some cases.

I haven't played with Windows recently, but you may find the technique of executing the relevant Windows commands using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module useful there as well.